# Proving using Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$ such that $f'$ is derivable at every point in $(a, b)$ and the chord passing through the points $(a, f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$ also passes through the point $(c, f(c))$ for a particular $a<c<b$, then prove that $f''(t)=0$ for some $a<t<b$.

Now the slope of the chord equals $$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=f'(k)$$ for some $a<k<c$ Now slope of the chord also equals $$\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}=f'(l)$$ for some $c<l<b$
So we get $f'(l)=f'(k)$ for two distinct points $a<l<k<b$ and as $f'$ is diifferentiable at all the interior points in $(a, b)$ so it satisfies all the conditions of the Rolle's Theorem for the interval $[l, k]$ So we get $f''(t)=0$ for some $a<l<t<k<b$
Is the proof correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct. You can get a slightly easier formulation if you use the same technique that is used in the proof of the mean value theorem from Rolle's theorem:

If $m=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ is the slope of the chord, then consider the difference of $f$ and the secant equation,
$$
h(x)=f(x)-f(a)-m(x-a).
$$
The function $h$ has roots at $a$ and $b$ by the definition of the chord, and also at $c$ by the additional assumption.

Thus by Rolle $h'$ has at least two roots and then $h''$ at least one root in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is also correct. You are using the mean value theorem in the first step, which is an easy consequence of Rolle's theorem.